# Flutter Slidable Grid

Tags: flutter

I want to create a grid 6x6 with, for example, a letter in each cell. When the user swipes a row horizontally (left/right) or a column vertically (up/down) i want the row/column to respond by shift the cells in the direction of the swipe. The cell on the end that would be moving out of the grid (In the direction that was swiped toward) disappears and a new cell comes in on the other side.

I'm a beginner with Flutter so i don't know where to go with this one.

This is what I've got.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<List<String>> gridData = [
    ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    ['G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'],
    ['M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R'],
    ['S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X'],
    ['Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Swipe Grid Demo'),
        ),
        body: SwipeGrid(gridData),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SwipeGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<List<String>> gridData;

  SwipeGrid(this.gridData);

  @override
  _SwipeGridState createState() => _SwipeGridState();
}

class _SwipeGridState extends State<SwipeGrid> {
  List<List<dynamic>> currentGridData = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentGridData = widget.gridData.map((row) => List.from(row)).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
        if (details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx > 0) {
          // Swiped right
          setState(() {
            shiftRight();
            fillGap();
          });
        } else {
          // Swiped left
          setState(() {
            shiftLeft();
            fillGap();
          });
        }
      },
      onVerticalDragEnd: (details) {
        if (details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dy > 0) {
          // Swiped down
          setState(() {
            shiftDown();
            fillGap();
          });
        } else {
          // Swiped up
          setState(() {
            shiftUp();
            fillGap();
          });
        }
      },
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: List.generate(
            currentGridData.length,
            (rowIndex) {
              return Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: List.generate(
                  currentGridData[rowIndex].length,
                  (colIndex) {
                    return Container(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 50,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                          currentGridData[rowIndex][colIndex],
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void shiftRight() {
    for (int i = 0; i < currentGridData.length; i++) {
      String lastItem = currentGridData[i].removeLast();
      currentGridData[i].insert(0, lastItem);
    }
    print(currentGridData);
    print("swipe right");
  }

  void shiftLeft() {
    for (int i = 0; i < currentGridData.length; i++) {
      String firstItem = currentGridData[i].removeAt(0);
      currentGridData[i].add(firstItem);
    }
    print(currentGridData);
    print("swipe left");
  }

  void shiftDown() {
    String lastRowFirstItem = currentGridData.last.removeAt(0);
    for (int i = currentGridData.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      currentGridData[i].insert(0, currentGridData[i - 1].removeAt(0));
    }
    currentGridData.first.add(lastRowFirstItem);
    print(currentGridData);
    print("swipe down");
  }

  void shiftUp() {
    String firstRowLastItem = currentGridData.first.removeLast();
    for (int i = 0; i < currentGridData.length - 1; i++) {
      currentGridData[i].add(currentGridData[i + 1].removeLast());
    }
    currentGridData.last.insert(0, firstRowLastItem);
    print(currentGridData);
    print("swipe up");
  }

  void fillGap() {
    final random = Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < currentGridData.length; i++) {
      if (currentGridData[i].contains(null)) {
        currentGridData[i] = currentGridData[i].map((letter) {
          return letter ?? String.fromCharCode(random.nextInt(26) + 65);
        }).toList();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The way that i am registering the swiping (for example swiping horizontally) `onHorizontalDragEnd` > `details.velocity.pixelsPerSecond.dx` doesnt seem to be working properly as sometimes i swipe right and it registers as left (or up, or down).

I hope my explanation makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const gridSize = 6;
const velocity = 60;

void main() {
  runApp(GridApp());
}

class GridApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Swipe Grid Demo')),
        body: GridWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GridWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<GridWidget> createState() => _GridWidgetState();
}

class _GridWidgetState extends State<GridWidget> {
  List<List<String>> gridData = [
    ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
    ['G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L'],
    ['M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R'],
    ['S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X'],
    ['Y', 'Z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: gridSize,
      ),
      itemCount: gridSize * gridSize,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        int row = index ~/ gridSize;
        int col = index % gridSize;
        String cellValue = gridData[row][col];

        return GestureDetector(
          onHorizontalDragEnd: (details) {
            if (details.primaryVelocity! < velocity) {
              swipeRowRight(row);
            } else if (details.primaryVelocity! > velocity) {
              swipeRowLeft(row);
            }
          },
          onVerticalDragEnd: (details) {
            if (details.primaryVelocity! < velocity) {
              swipeColumnDown(col);
            } else if (details.primaryVelocity! > velocity) {
              swipeColumnUp(col);
            }
          },
          child: Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                cellValue,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void swipeRowLeft(int row) {
    setState(() {
      String firstCell = gridData[row].removeAt(0);

      gridData[row].add(firstCell);
    });
  }

  void swipeRowRight(int row) {
    setState(() {
      String lastCell = gridData[row].removeLast();

      gridData[row].insert(0, lastCell);
    });
  }

  void swipeColumnUp(int column) {
    setState(() {
      String firstCell = gridData[0][column];

      for (int i = 0; i < gridSize - 1; i++) {
        gridData[i][column] = gridData[i + 1][column];
      }

      gridData[gridSize - 1][column] = firstCell;
    });
  }

  void swipeColumnDown(int column) {
    setState(() {
      String lastCell = gridData[gridSize - 1][column];

      for (int i = gridSize - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        gridData[i][column] = gridData[i - 1][column];
      }

      gridData[0][column] = lastCell;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: This has got the column and row functionality but i can't seem to get an accurate swipe direction. I had this same problem before. Sometimes when i swipe right it says i swiped left etc.